# CakePHP "missing table" error when table should not exist

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm getting the following error:

```
 Array (
     [0] => Missing table 'TEST_USERS'. If running from a test you may need to add 'app.TEST_USER' to the fixtures array. See output
 below for more details.
     [1] => Array
         (
             [className] => TESTUSER
             [table] => TEST_USERS
             [code] => 500
         ) 
 )
```

The table does not exist.

The table should not exist.

I grepped my code and found no reference to TEST_USERS, TESTUSERS or TEST.USERS.

I do have a table called USERS_TEST.

Can I get some trouble shooting hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the code that's throwing that error. It's probably a missconstructed array to save, since it seems to be the name convention for a HABTM table.

Comment: Is `JURISS_` a table prefix? Is it a habtm join table (if so the names are the wrong way round)? Add the full stack trace for the error to the question please (why is the table and class name upper case?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I changed:

```
var $useTable = 'TEST';
```

to:

```
var $useTable = 'test';
```

and it worked.